# Pass Jenkins variable to Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-cli

Currently i'm trying to echo the name of the user that trigger a build using

> $BUILD_USER_ID

from the user vars plugin, but from there i'm unsure as to how to pass this into my ruby scripts, i did this in a batch commmand:

> set USER= $BUILD_USER_ID

and this is what i have in my ruby file:

> ENV['USER']

But it return weird bunch of letters, which im guesing is the user name in the slave node i'm using to run the job.

is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your plugin with the [envinject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to inject environment variables in your Jenkins job.

I've created a jenkins job and installed both plugins. I've ticked the "Set jenkins user build variables".
I've also ticked: "Inject environment variables to the build process" and define inside the "Properties Content":

```
USER = $BUILD_USER_ID
```

This will create a new environment variable `USER` with as content the content of the variable BUILD_USER_ID (which is created by the user env plugin).

To test:

I've created a file.rb which contains my ruby code to print an environment variable (just in the shell).

```
# write script
echo "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" > file.rb
echo "# Print some variables" >> file.rb
echo "puts ENV['BUILD_USER_ID']" >> file.rb

# execute script
ruby file.rb
```

Output:

```
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
USER=$BUILD_USER_ID

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3544234152865572985.sh
+ echo #!/usr/bin/env ruby
+ echo # Print some variables
+ echo puts ENV['USER']
+ ruby file.rb
admin
Finished: SUCCESS
```